# AWS Lambda Error:No public method named 'minFunction' with appropriate method signature found on class

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting an error when i tried testing my first AWS lambda implementation. Below are the details

**Java code**

```
package PK;

public class Sample {


       public static void main(String[] args) {
              int a = 11;
              int b = 6;
              int c = minFunction(a, b);
              System.out.println("Minimum Value = " + c);

       }

        public static int minFunction(int n1, int n2) {
            int min;
            if (n1 > n2)
               min = n2;
            else
               min = n1;

            return min; 
         }

}
```

Handler  - >  PK.Sample::minFunction

Test Event - >

{
  "key1": 1,
  "key2": 5
}

Please let me know if anything wrong here.
My understanding is, we have to update the method name in 'Handler' & Parameter value in 'Test Event'

Answer (score 0):

Your function handler is incorrect. The correct format is documented here:

- [AWS Lambda function handler in Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler.html)

From the docs, an example handler interface is as follows:

```
// Handler value: example.Handler
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, String>{
  @Override
  public String handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context)
```